# Is there a fix to this error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I just started to learn how to draw using the Graphics class in C# but there is this one error in my project in a script called ,"Form1.Designer.cs". Here is the code:

```
    namespace Pong
{
    partial class FrmMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // FrmMain
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 729);
            this.Name = "FrmMain";
            this.Text = "PONG";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FrmMain_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Line that has "this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FrmMain_Load);" is the part that is the error. This is the error code I got in the output:

[image: Error]

I have a script that makes the graphic called ,"Form1.cs" ,that calls the InitializeComponent() function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pong
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Brush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            g.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 50, 50, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not the best at debugging, so if anyone could debug this glitch it would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: How can this question be specific to C# 2, 3 and 4? Read the tag descriptions and don't use those that are not specifically relevant.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, including error messages. Post the text, formatted appropriately.

Comment: I have provided an answer to the specific question you asked but you have another problem. You appear to want to handle the `Paint` event of the form but you're not. I'm guessing what you actually did was double-click the form to create a `Load` event handler, then just change the name and the signature and assumed that that would magically handle the `Paint` event instead. It won't. Once you've followed the instructions in my answer, open the *Properties* window and click the *Events* button and take a look. That's where you create, select and remove event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. Your designer code is trying to register a handler for the form's `Load` event but there is no method with the specified name. Why is that the case in the first place? I'm guessing that you deleted that method while it was still registered as an event handler. Don't do that because this is what happens. If you want to delete an event handler then you have to remove the registration first, which you do in the *Properties* window of the designer.

Now that you're in this situation, you can just delete that line from the designer code file and that will fix the issue. If you don't try to register a nonexistent method as an event handler then you won't have that problem.